# SQL DISTINCT in the middle of select

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Does the distinct need to always be the first line after the select? Every time I try the following, I get a syntax error near the keyword 'DISTINCT, if not, how can I make the distinct work without begin the after the select.

```
SELECT COLUMN1,
DISTINCT COLUMN 2,
COLUMNM 3

FROM TABLE_1
```

it works if I have the distinct at in the first line like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN2,
COLUMN1,
COLUMN3

FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: Distinct applies to full row, not a single field. What is that you are really trying to do?

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired results. `DISTINCT` is probably not the functionality you are wanting here.

Comment: If you got multiple rows with the same `column2/column3` combination which value for `column1` do you expect to get returned? You need a rule for this and then it might be as simple as a `group by column2,column3` or filtering on a  `row_number`

Comment: Putting `distinct` anywhere else other than right after the `select` is invalid SQL and will result in an error

Comment: what is the result that you are expecting, may be we can try some other query

Answer (score 5):

The `DISTINCT` clause filters out FULL DUPLICATE ROWS. It goes right after the `SELECT` keyword, since it applies to the entire row, not single columns. You cannot use it in between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I know where does this confusion comes from. While `DISTINCT` is indeed an optional `SELECT` predicate, which acts on each output row as a whole it can also be used inside function argument (which is also a statement on its own), e.g.:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name SEPARATOR "; "), ...
FROM subjects AS s
LEFT JOIN property AS p ON p.subject_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN property2 AS p2 ON p2.subject_id = s.id
...
GROUP BY s.id;
```

The purpose of `DISTINCT` here is self-explanatory. But again, if we look at this inner statement `DISTINCT` comes first.
Another example of same kind would be `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`.